# Push all the files from SVN repository to GitHub repository using jenkins job

Tags: git, jenkins, tortoisesvn

I've configured the SVN repository in my local system which has jenkins too. Once I started the builds in jenkins, all the new files which are present in SVN repository is synced into the jenkins work-space perfectly.

Now what I want to do is: once I'm done with all the changes with the files in SVN repository [modification] the jenkins job needs to send all the new changes to the GitHub repository from the jenkins work-space or directly from SVN repository to GitHub repository.

How can I do that process?

Comment: Is it also a git repository?

Comment: It's a GitHub Repository [Private Repositories]

**bold**"I need to push the files from SVN to GitHub once the file is modified on SVN Repositories"**bold**

Comment: The just run the command from jenkins
`git add <files that changed>`
`git commit -m "You message"`
`git push`

Comment: From command line the new file is uploaded to GitHub but how can i do that push file from UI end.[from post build action].

In Post-Build Action it need to identify the modified file automatically and need to push those file to GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

[I've a project in jenkins as "freestyle" in which i'm linking the SVN Repositories path as a source. Once the build is completed all the files which are present in SVN Repositories  are migrated to jenkins workspace as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Vuru.png)

[In the same jenking job "post action" I'm trying to move those all/changed files to GitHub Repositories, but it's not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNoK2.png)

How to move that files to github Repositories ?